# How to remove certain nodes in an xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

Does any one know how to make the following transformation using xslt?

Source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <termEntry id="1">
   <langSet lang="eng-us">
    <ntig>
     <termGrp>
      <term></term>
     </termGrp>
    </ntig>
    <ntig>
     <termGrp>
      <term></term>
     </termGrp>
    </ntig>
   </langSet>

   <langSet lang="ara-ae">
    <ntig>
     <termGrp>
      <term>123</term>
     </termGrp>
    </ntig>
   </langSet>
</termEntry>

<termEntry id="2">
 <langSet lang="eng-us">
  <ntig>
   <termGrp>
    <term></term>
   </termGrp>
  </ntig>
  <ntig>
   <termGrp>
    <term></term>
   </termGrp>
  </ntig>
  <ntig>
   <termGrp>
    <term>123</term>
   </termGrp>
  </ntig>
 </langSet>
</termEntry>
</body>
```

**Request:**
1.if the value in `<term></term>` is null\empty, delete its grandparent node, namely

```
<ntig></ntig>
```

2.In this way, if all `<term>` tags are empty, delete the whole `<langset>` node.

**Expected result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <termEntry id="1">

   <langSet lang="ara-ae">
    <ntig>
     <termGrp>
      <term>123</term>
     </termGrp>
    </ntig>
   </langSet>
  </termEntry>

  <termEntry id="2">
   <langSet lang="eng-us">
    <ntig>
     <termGrp>
      <term>123</term>
     </termGrp>
    </ntig>
   </langSet>
 </termEntry>
</body>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my solution for a complete, short and easy solution, that unlike the other answer, strictly implements the requirements of the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

The identity transform plus a couple of simple empty templates is what you need here. You want to copy all your input to the output unless it meets your criteria, in which case you want to suppress it.

A stylesheet such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ntig[descendant::term[. = '']]"/>
    <xsl:template match="langSet[not(descendant::term[. != ''])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will do what you need. The template which matches `ntig` elements will suppress those elements with empty `term` grandchildren. The template which matches `langSet` elements suppresses those `langSets` where there are no descendant `term` elements which have content.

Comment: Hi Nic, I wanted to test by adding '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="FM_Nic.xsl"?> ' And after click the xml, only text values are displayed **123 123** Instead of expected codes... Do I need to add more references?

Comment: By the way, I wonder if I can generate the new xml instead of viewing. And How? By **not** using other programing langugages, say java

Comment: @Jackie - see @Dimitre's answer for a good explanation of why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ntig[not(*/term[string-length()>0])]"/>
 <xsl:template match="langSet[not(*/*/term[string-length()>0])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<body>
    <termEntry id="1">
        <langSet lang="eng-us">
            <ntig>
                <termGrp>
                    <term></term>
                </termGrp>
            </ntig>
            <ntig>
                <termGrp>
                    <term></term>
                </termGrp>
            </ntig>
        </langSet>
        <langSet lang="ara-ae">
            <ntig>
                <termGrp>
                    <term>123</term>
                </termGrp>
            </ntig>
        </langSet>
    </termEntry>
    <termEntry id="2">
        <langSet lang="eng-us">
            <ntig>
                <termGrp>
                    <term></term>
                </termGrp>
            </ntig>
            <ntig>
                <termGrp>
                    <term></term>
                </termGrp>
            </ntig>
            <ntig>
                <termGrp>
                    <term>123</term>
                </termGrp>
            </ntig>
        </langSet>
    </termEntry>
</body>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<body>
   <termEntry id="1">
      <langSet lang="ara-ae">
         <ntig>
            <termGrp>
               <term>123</term>
            </termGrp>
         </ntig>
      </langSet>
   </termEntry>
   <termEntry id="2">
      <langSet lang="eng-us">
         <ntig>
            <termGrp>
               <term>123</term>
            </termGrp>
         </ntig>
      </langSet>
   </termEntry>
</body>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule (template) copies every node "as-is".
2. The template overriding the identity rule for `ntig[not(*/term[string-length()>0])]` has an empty body -- this effectively ignores (deletes) any `ntig` element that doesn't have at lest one `term` grandchild with positive `string-length()`.
3. The template overriding the identity rule for `langSet[not(*/*/term[string-length()>0])]` has an empty body -- this effectively ignores (deletes) any `langSet` element that doesn't have at lest one `term` great-grandchild with positive `string-length()`.

**Do note** that specifying templates like this violates the definition of the problem:

```
<xsl:template match="ntig[descendant::term[. = '']]"/> 
<xsl:template match="langSet[not(descendant::term[. != ''])]"/>
```

Because the requirement is to "if the value in  is null\empty, delete its *grandparent* node".

However, the first template above deletes not only the grand-parent `ntig`, but *any ancestor* `ntig`.

**The current solution does not commit such a mistake**.

Comment: @Dimitre: Hi Dimitre, I wanted to test by adding '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="FM_Dimi.xsl"?> ' And after click the xml, only text values are displayed **123 123** Instead of expected codes... Do I need to add more references? By the way, I wonder if I can generate the new xml instead of viewing. And How? By **not** using other programing langugages, say java

Comment: @Jackie: this is because the PI gets re-generated and IE (and probably other browsers) interprete this as an endless loop... The proper way to develop with XSLT is by using an XSLT IDE. I am using both XSelerator and oXygen and I never use a browser to run/test an XSLT transformation. Other, uglier ways are to invoke the particular XSLT processor from the command line.

Comment: @Dimitre, +1 for being absolutely right although I suspect you are splitting hairs in this particular case :)

Comment: @Nic-Gibson: Following the OP's requirements as closely as possible is not splitting hairs -- not following them exactly enforces inexact practices and may indicate to people that XPath is not powerful enough to deal with the exact requirements.

Comment: @Jackie: To prevent this behavior of the in-browser transformation, add this template: `<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()"/>`

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks for further explanations, which is very helpful. However, the same thing occurs even after adding the template   
 
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()"/>
Namely, only 123 123 are displayed.

So you mean XSLT IDE can solve my question? By the way, I wonder if I can generate the new xml instead of viewing. And How? By not using other programing langugages, say java

Comment: @Jackie: Read the documentation of your XSLT processor -- how to invoke it from the command line. I am working every day with 9 different XSLT processors (Saxon 6.5.4 and 9.x, Msxml3,4,6, .NET XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform, AltovaXML (XMLSpy), XQSharp). Each one of these has its own command-line syntax.

Comment: @Dimitre: It seems I need to study how to use at least one of those processors. Will let you know when there is a testing result. 
Cheers

Comment: @Jackie: Yes, I recommend to use the same XSLT processor that your browser is using (in case your final solution will be applied within the browser). For IE this is msxml3 (or 6) and the corresponding command-line utility is msxsl.exe.